# How to define pattern of file names in vscode to linter a language

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm sorry if title is not clear. Let me have an example.

I use vscode and I have a Docker project with below structure:

```
project1

- compose
-- docker-compse-main.yml
-- docker-compse-backend.yml
-- docker-compse-frontend.yml

- dockerfile
-- Dockerfile_main
-- Dockerfile_backend
-- Dockerfile_frontend

- html
-- # project files
```

I have installed some linters that if the file name is `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`, it detects them as `Dockerfile` and `compose` files and highlights them.

But what I want is: each file starts with `Dockerfile`, it acts as a `Dockerfile`. Like if I open `Dockerfile_backend`, there's no highlighting and I should manually change it to `Dockerfile`.

And each file starts with `docker-compose` should be seen as a `compose` file with `compose` syntax highlighting.

Is that possible in vscode?

If yes, I don't know what to add in `settings.json` to tell vscode.

The list of extensions I use for this matter is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer, here it is:

Open `settings.json` file and add this:

```
{
    # Your other settings are here
    # here starts my files.associations
    "files.associations": {
        "Dockerfile_*": "dockerfile",
        "docker-compose*.yml": "dockercompose"
    },
}
```